# Having a rectangle and histogram plot in ggplot2 match up exactly in width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a rectangular plot in ggplot that lines up exactly with the histogram above it. Does anyone have any idea on how to line up the widths of both components of the plot?

Here's the plot.
[image: Here's the plot]

Here's the code to produce the plot.

```
sunburst <- ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="x") +
  ylim(-0.003540187, 0.004720250) +
  geom_rect(data=stroma_comp, mapping=aes(xmin=lower_lim, xmax=upper_lim,
                                          ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,
                                          fill = stroma_bins), color='black', alpha=1) +
  geom_col(data = plot_sample,
           mapping = aes(x = row_id, y = cd8_density_total, fill = '#D3D3D3'),
           color='dark gray',
           alpha=1,
           position = position_dodge(0)) + # columns on outer level
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = -0.003540187, label = paste(sample_name, "\n", indication, "\n", pheno), size = 5,
           color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("0-10%" = "#FF7100",
                               "10-20%" = "#eb8e00",
                               "20-30%" = "#d4a600",
                               "30-40%" = "#bbb908",
                               "40-50%" = "#a1ca3c",
                               "50-60%" = "#85d865",
                               "60-70%" = "#66e58e",
                               "70-80%" = "#41efb6",
                               "80-90%" = "#0df8dd",
                               "90-100%" = "#00ffff"), guide = "none") +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill='transparent')
  )
```

And here are the dataframes used to produce them.

```
dput(stroma_comp)
structure(list(stroma_bins = structure(9:10, levels = c("0-10%", 
"10-20%", "20-30%", "30-40%", "40-50%", "50-60%", "60-70%", "70-80%", 
"80-90%", "90-100%"), class = "factor"), n = c(1.09, 6.09), upper_lim = c(1.09, 
7.18), lower_lim = c(0, 1.09), ymax = c(0, 0), ymin = c(-0.002360125, 
-0.002360125)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

dput(plot_sample)
structure(list(Image = c("MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1"
), Name = c("Tile 6", "Tile 3", "Tile 5", "Tile 2", "Tile 7", 
"Tile 4", "Tile 1"), tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Epithelium.area.Âµm.2 = c(98.9314, 
8.9938, 78.9453, 165.885, 43.9696, 82.9425, 55.9612), tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Necrosis.area.Âµm.2 = c(18.9868, 
0, 1.9986, 116.919, 0, 0, 0), tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Stroma.area.Âµm.2 = c(50773.8184, 
3895.3008, 29928.2617, 71677.3322, 58207.6645, 15441.3, 21588.0416
), tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2..Tumor.area.Âµm.2 = c(7216, 56.9605, 
340.7639, 3572.5244, 1564.9156, 1187.1774, 1162.1947), Area.Âµm.2 = c(94309.7, 
11209.7, 46866.9, 102262.6, 88348.2, 17987.8, 57560.1), ID = c("MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 6", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 3", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 5", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 2", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 7", 
"MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 4", "MW055 IF_Scan1.qptiff - resolution #1-Tile 1"
), num_tumor_detections = c(52, 0, 0, 29, 11, 6, 12), tumor_cd45 = c(13, 
0, 0, 16, 8, 6, 8), tumor_cd8 = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), tumor_epi = c(35, 
0, 0, 12, 3, 0, 3), tumor_stromal = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), num_stroma_detections = c(290, 
16, 172, 350, 298, 105, 117), stroma_cd45 = c(163, 14, 117, 168, 
184, 72, 80), stroma_cd8 = c(11, 0, 5, 16, 13, 4, 5), stroma_epi = c(10, 
1, 3, 19, 0, 3, 2), stroma_stromal = c(106, 1, 47, 147, 101, 
26, 30), num_epi_detections = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), epi_cd45 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), epi_cd8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), epi_epi = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), epi_stromal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), num_necro_detections = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), necro_cd45 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), necro_cd8 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), necro_epi = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), necro_stromal = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), total_cells = c(342, 16, 172, 379, 309, 111, 
129), total_cd8 = c(15, 0, 5, 16, 13, 4, 6), total_epithelial = c(45, 
1, 3, 31, 3, 3, 5), tissue_area = c(58107.7366, 3961.2551, 30349.9695, 
75532.6606, 59816.5497, 16711.4199, 22806.1975), cd8_percent = c(0.043859649122807, 
0, 0.0290697674418605, 0.0422163588390501, 0.0420711974110032, 
0.036036036036036, 0.0465116279069767), cd8_density_stroma = c(0.000216647089910417, 
0, 0.000167066168096225, 0.000223222593655627, 0.000223338285630752, 
0.000259045546683246, 0.000231609707478051), cd8_density_tumor = c(0.000554323725055432, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000860441025931369), cd8_density_total = c(0.000258141185282374, 
0, 0.000164744811358048, 0.000211828894585503, 0.000217331157768199, 
0.000239357279269848, 0.000263086382550182), stroma_percentage = c(0.873787577539202, 
0.983350150814574, 0.986105165608157, 0.948958127922744, 0.973103008982145, 
0.923996889097377, 0.94658662848114), cd8_density_ratio = c(2.55864837734328, 
NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.71504733243062), stroma_bins = structure(c(9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("0-10%", "10-20%", 
"20-30%", "30-40%", "40-50%", "50-60%", "60-70%", "70-80%", "80-90%", 
"90-100%"), class = "factor"), cd8_percent_bins = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("0-2% CD8+ Cells", "2-4% CD8+ Cells", 
"4-6% CD8+ Cells", "6-8% CD8+ Cells", "8-10% CD8+ Cells", "10-15% CD8+ Cells", 
"15-20% CD8+ Cells", ">20% CD8+ Cells"), class = "factor"), row_id = 1:7), row.names = c(1584L, 
1581L, 1583L, 1580L, 1585L, 1582L, 1579L), class = "data.frame")
```

Apologies for the super long dataframes.

Comment: Something is missing from your code around `lower_lim)/2, y = ymin/2,
90, size = 2, color = "black")`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, it was some code I commented out in my IDE, but I guess I didn't remove it completely. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescale the x coordinates for `geom_col()` to fit into the range of `geom_rect()`. Then align things with the arguments `width` and `just` in `geom_col()`. Here is what that can look like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

max_x_rect <- max(stroma_comp$upper_lim)
max_row_id <- max(plot_sample$row_id)

scale <- max_x_rect / max_row_id

ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="x") +
  ylim(-0.003540187, 0.004720250) +
  geom_rect(data=stroma_comp, mapping=aes(xmin=lower_lim, xmax=upper_lim,
                                          ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,
                                          fill = stroma_bins), color='black', alpha=1) +
  geom_col(data = plot_sample,
           mapping = aes(x = scale * row_id, y = cd8_density_total, fill = '#D3D3D3'),
           color='dark gray',
           width = 1,
           alpha = 1,
           just = 1,
           position = position_dodge(0)) + # columns on outer level
  #annotate("text", x = 1, y = -0.003540187, label = paste(sample_name, "\n", indication, "\n", pheno), size = 5,
  #         color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("0-10%" = "#FF7100",
                               "10-20%" = "#eb8e00",
                               "20-30%" = "#d4a600",
                               "30-40%" = "#bbb908",
                               "40-50%" = "#a1ca3c",
                               "50-60%" = "#85d865",
                               "60-70%" = "#66e58e",
                               "70-80%" = "#41efb6",
                               "80-90%" = "#0df8dd",
                               "90-100%" = "#00ffff"), guide = "none") +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill='transparent')
  )
```

[image]